# issue with Response.Redirect while using masterpage

Tags: c#, response.redirect, master-pages

I am developing a project using C#.net. Here in master page I have a button for search which will redirect to different pages in the project.

I am using "~/searchpage.aspx" for redirecting to other pages which some pages are in root folder and sub-root folders. All pages are inheriting the master page file.

Response.Redirect("~/testSearch.aspx");

The above code breaking  in some scenarios. which is the best approach to redirect to other pages from master page.

Answer (score 2):

`Response.Redirect` uses client relative URLs (it's setting the HTTP Location header), as such, you don't need the preceding `~`.

Try `Response.Redirect("/testSearch.aspx");`

Answer (score 1):

maybe `Response.Redirect("/testSearch.aspx");`

Answer (score 1):

could you try
 `Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveClientUrl("/testSearch.aspx"));`